# Cast an object that is pointed by an iterator

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, iterator

I have this multiset container:

```
multiset<IMidiMsgExt, IMidiMsgExtComp> queuedNotes;
```

`IMidiMsgExt` is a struct I've created myself (I need it for one additional property, `mTick`) that extend [IMidiMsg](https://github.com/majek/wdl/blob/master/WDL/IPlug/IPlugStructs.h#L159) :

```
struct IMidiMsgExt : public IMidiMsg
{
    IMidiMsgExt() {
    }

    double mTick = 0.;

    void IMidiMsgExt::MakeNoteOnMsg(int noteNumber, int velocity, int offset, double tick, int channel)
    {
        Clear();
        mStatus = channel | (kNoteOn << 4);
        mData1 = noteNumber;
        mData2 = velocity;
        mOffset = offset;
        mTick = tick;
    }

    void IMidiMsgExt::MakeNoteOffMsg(int noteNumber, int offset, double tick, int channel)
    {
        Clear();
        mStatus = channel | (kNoteOff << 4);
        mData1 = noteNumber;
        mOffset = offset;
        mTick = tick;
    }

    void IMidiMsgExt::Clear()
    {
        mOffset = 0;
        mStatus = mData1 = mData2 = 0;
        mTick = 0.;
    }
};
```

Next: I store in that `queuedNotes` multiset some `IMidiMsgExt` objects, with:

```
IMidiMsgExt* noteOff = new IMidiMsgExt;
noteOff->MakeNoteOffMsg(57, 0, tickSize * 111, 0);
queuedNotes.insert(*noteOff);
```

Now, I need to use a function called `SendMidiMsg(IMidiMsg* pMsg)` (that takes `IMidiMsg` type as input) sending my object `IMidiMsgExt` to it.

I extract the first object from my list to an iterator:

```
auto midiMessage = queuedNotes.begin();
```

But when I try to cast it and use `SendMidiMsg`:

```
SendMidiMsg((IMidiMsgExt*)midiMessage);
```

it says `no suitable conversion function from "std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<IMidiMsgExt>>>" to "IMidiMsg *" exists`

Where am I wrong? Should I use `dynamic casting`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
auto midiMessage = queuedNotes.begin();
```

`midiMessage` is of type `std::multiset::iterator`. And it is not convertable to your type `IMidiMsgExt`. Iterator is an object that behaves similarly to a pointer, so you can use dereference operator (`*`) to get the object that it "points to". You also don't need to cast derived object to its base, that is done implicitly. All you need to do is get the address of where the iterator "points to" to get a pointer to `IMidiMsgExt`:

```
SendMidiMsg(&*midiMessage);
```

A quick break down of `&*midiMessage`:

```
  variable    -     type
midiMessage   - std::multiset::iterator
*midiMessage  - IMidiMsgExt
&*midiMessage - IMidiMsgExt*
```

---

**Edit:** 
About your const_iterator error. [std::multiset::begin() is supposed to always return const_iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038453/c-standard-unexpected-const-iterator-in-multiset). Your function `SendMidiMsg()` wants a non const pointer - it is saying it wants to edit the message. `multiset` does not allow changing the elements.

You can copy the message and then call `SendMidiMsg()`. If you don't need the message inside the container anymore, you can also erase it afterwards.

```
auto msg = *midiMessage;
SendMidiMsg(&msg);
queuedNotes.erase(midiMessage);
```

**Note:** It seems like you have a memory leak in the program. You create messages with new and I don't see any calls to delete, to release the memory.

```
IMidiMsgExt* noteOff = new IMidiMsgExt;
noteOff->MakeNoteOffMsg(57, 0, tickSize * 111, 0);
queuedNotes.insert(*noteOff);
```

Comment: But it says: `argument of type "const IMidiMsgExt *" is incompatible with parameter of type "IMidiMsg *"`

Comment: @paizza That meas that `queuedNotes.begin()` returns a `const_iterator`. If you dereference a `const_iterator` it returns a const reference to the object. Your `SendMidiMsg()` expect a non const pointer. You have a conceptual error in your progrem. You are trying to modify something you said should not be modified.

Comment: I can't change `SendMidiMsg()`, since it's a method within the Framework I'll use. The only way is to change the `iterator` returning type. But also there: I cannot edit `multiset` list. Should I need to change container? Somethings that store and return a non-const element?

Comment: No. The question is why do you get a `const_iterator`. You must have a const reference to `queuedNotes`. It would help if you show the code before you call `SendMidiMsg()`. The ineresting bit is where do you get `queuedNotes` from before you call `begin()` on it.

Comment: Before `begin` I just check this: `while (queuedNotes.size() > 0)`. Than auto and that function. I decleare `multiset<IMidiMsgExt, IMidiMsgExtComp> queuedNotes;` within a .h file.

Comment: And I use this `comparator` struct IMidiMsgExtComp {
 bool operator()(const IMidiMsgExt& lhs, const IMidiMsgExt& rhs) {
  return lhs.mTick < rhs.mTick;
 }
};

Comment: On comparator there is `const`. That would be the problem?

Comment: I don't think! If I remove const in the method, nothing change! It's all the same.

Comment: Which other code would you like to see? I don't have any. after `multiset<IMidiMsgExt, IMidiMsgExtComp> queuedNotes;` I just insert object with `.insert(*noteOff)` as stated in the question.

Comment: @paizza Hm very strange. Try using the type instead of auto like: `std::multiset::iterator midiMessage = queuedNotes.begin();` If this doesn't work then I don't know. `begin()` should return an `iterator` and not a `const_iterator` if `queuedNotes` is not const qualified.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109797/discussion-between-paizza-and-rozina).